# Modified Vega: Why did Taleb in Dynamic Hedging use "Multiplying by 10" in building Exposure Vector - Chapter 9 - Page 160

Tags: statistics

On Page 160, Dynamic Hedging by Taleb, he builds Exposure Vector and writes -

***"The trader then builds the exposure vector, using for input the vegas for 10 percent change in volatility (i.e. P/L resulting from volatility moving from 15% to 16.5%) and multiplying every one by 10 times the corresponding V (Daily volatility).***

Why did Taleb multiply daily volatility by 10?

If 10% change is required by volatility moving from 15% to 16.5%, I understand a correct multiplication factor should have been 1.5 (Taleb explains this on Page 147-148).

Though I could arrive at the VAR of $21000 that Taleb mentions on Page 161 (by using the formulas in chapter 9 and Module E), I could not decode a suitable reason for multiplying daily volatility by 10, as I mention above?

What am I missing? I suppose something very trivial.

Comment: The factor from 15 to 16.5 is 1.1, or an addition of 10% of 15. 1.5 does not occur as factor, it is the additive increment.

Comment: LutzL, 1.1 might help explain. But Taleb writes on Page 147-148 as follows - "If volatility is 18% and the vega is 0.5.........Some people could derive the vega for 1.8 moves in implied volatility (10%).....Their vega will then be 1.8 times 0.5 = 0.9". If your logic is right, Taleb here should have mentioned 1.1 instead of 1.8

Comment: The whole construct looks loosely like the decibel definition, where the perceived impression behaves like $10\log_{10}$ of the physical energy behind it. The important part is the logarithmic relationship, the 10 as base and factor is not necessary, just serves to get handy numbers.

Comment: Sorry, that looks not very intelligible. Seemingly, the 18%=0.18 is translated to 18, and then 10% of that is taken, which is the same as multiplying the original number by 10. The question is if the percent sign is just a decoration on the number or a unit equal to 0.01. Taleb seems to lean toward the decoration meaning.

Comment: Yeah. But, that is the lingo of the trading floor which Taleb keeps using. What Taleb is correct about though is say if you have vega1 for 1% increase (18% to 19% volatility), and then if you need the vega2 for 10% change (18% to 19.8% volatility), this vega2 will be vega1 times 1.8. Note, how in case1 it is a 1% increase and in case2 it is a 10% change. This is consistent since the 1% volatility increase at 18% is equivalent to 5.6% change in 18%; and therefore a 10% volatility change at 18% is equivalent to a change of (10%./5.6%) = 1.8 times the 1% volatility increase.

Comment: No, vega2 is 1.1*vega1 or 1.8+vega1. The last formulation is again correct and reflects the distribution law of arithmetic.

Comment: I disagree. Option vega does not work that way. Consider a convex graph of option price vs volatility. At any tangential point, if the volatility changes by 5.6% and the corresponding vega is vega1, then when at the same tangential point, if the volatility changes by 10%, the vega2 would by 1.8 times vega1 (because the change in case 2 is 1.8 times the change of case1).  When volatility increases, the front month option vega increases not in additive manner but in steps closely replicated by geometric growth.

Comment: For VAR calculation, one might even have to take 3 standard deviation or more and additive might be completely insufficient way to asses risk. But your explanation of 1.1 solves the dilemma at hand but seems it isn't very consistent with option theory. Bachelier's arithmetic distrbution might be true but only in extreme cases

Comment: The distribution law of arithmetic is $a(b+c)=ab+ac$, it does not have extremal cases. OK, if vega, and vega1, vega2 are functions and not constants, the meaning of the words can be different, addition can become multiplication and vv.

Comment: We are digressing. When you mention "if vega are functions and not constants", it seems you are unfamiliar with options terminology. I will wait for somebody else to reply. But thanks again, I'll ponder on your suggestion of 1.1. Time out LutzL

Comment: There is a quantitative finance board, http://quant.stackexchange.com. You might reach more experts there.

Comment: Thanks. That might be really helpful. Checked your page. Hats off to your reputation and the people reached. Will come back to you for more mathematical advice in future.